# Unable to install Oibaf's drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

Here's the link to [Oibaf's Drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers/) , I tried to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And all worked fine, But when i run `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`
It gives`: Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo`
and `sudo lshw -c video`
gives

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:281 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I have AMD Radeon R5 M430 inside , but currently on Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) graphics due to no drivers ( which I came to know somewhere And I am not really sure of).

Please help me use my graphics card.

EDIT: I did something else but posted something else.

Comment: Your title seems rather misleading. A title that matches your question will attract more appropriate help. Your `sudo apt install` instruction did not specify *what* should be installed, so did nothing. Re-read the instructions and do that line again properly.

Comment: @user535733 I updated the post. I didnt type sudo apt install but this.

Comment: Okay, you added a *source*, but you seem to have not installed any *software* from that source. You must tell apt exactly which packages you want to install.